# How to link a storage bucket file into an item in a table

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

How can I link a file in my storage bucket into a table?

Let's say I have an item like this

```
Name: user, CreatedAt: date, pfp: storageFile
```

I want the file to be linked to the `pfp` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would store the image URL in your database table. You can follow on of the user management tutorials here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-react#bonus-profile-photos